# Java alternative code for C# var type

Tags: java, selenium

In C#, implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type. But in Java, we need to set the data type explicitly. How to write the below code in Java

The following code:

```
var newPostlink = message.findElement(By.tagName("a"))[0];
```

Believe, we need to set this as an array type but am struggling with how to write the piece of code

In C#

```
public static void GoToNewPost() {
var message = Driver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("message"));
var newPostlink = message.findElement(By.tagName("a"))[0];
newPostlink.click();
```

In Java :

```
public static void GoToNewPost() {
WebElement message = Driver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("message"));
var newPostlink = message.findElement(By.tagName("a"))[0];
newPostlink.click();
```

Comment: message.findElement returns just 1 value, correct? So, are you trying to access the 0th element in that single element?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Do you know what the first element within your <a> tag is?
In any case, as per [this link](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)) You'd get WebElement as a return value. So why not make newPostlink  of WebElement type?

Comment: You may be interested in looking at Groovy and Geb, which makes this sort of code much simpler to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
??? newPostlink = message.findElement(By.tagName("a"))[0];
```

Here you are calling the method `findElement` on an object of the type `WebElement`. According to the documentation, this method returns a type `WebElement`:

> `WebElement`  findElement(`By` by)
>
> Find the first WebElement using the given method.

This is a single object, not an array, so you cannot use the array indexing operator on it in Java, so you cannot put `[0]` behind it.

Looking at the C# documentation, the situation is exactly the same. So the most likely answer is: you posted the wrong code, and you actually meant to invoke `findElements` (plural) in that line.

In that case, the Java version returns a `List<WebElement>` and you can get element zero like this:

```
WebElement newPostlink = message.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(0);
```

But that is a bit pointless, since this is exactly what the `findElement` method does already: it returns the first of the elements that was found.

So what you really want is to get rid of the `[0]` and then use `WebElement` as the type of `newPostlink`:

```
WebElement newPostlink = message.findElement(By.tagName("a"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the [Lombok `val` type](https://projectlombok.org/features/val.html), which is almost exactly like the C# `var` keyword, except that it is also declared as `final` (like C#'s `readonly`).

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 10, there is actually Type Inference for local variables, see [JEP-286](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

You can just write:

```
var user = new User();
```

However, you can only use it for local variables and variables in for and for-each loops. No fields or method return values.

Another limitation is that you mus immediately assign a value to the variable, this does not work:

```
var user;
user = new User();
```

You cannot assign null though. Note that it is still static typing, compiler just infers the type at compile-time and the resulting bytecode does contain the type information same as if you would declare the type explicitly. This means the performance is not affected as there is no additional processing at runtime.

You can download JDK 10 Early Access build [here](http://jdk.java.net/10/).

For more details, see [this blog post](http://vojtechruzicka.com/java-10-var-local-variable-type-inference-jep-286/) I wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Java is strongly typed and doesn't have inferred typing.  The other answer solves your problem but to your other question, you unfortunately can't get the compiler to infer types for your variables.

Comment: That is not true at all. The `var` keyword _is_ strongly typed. The issue is that you have to declare the variable type on the left of the equals and then assign it the same type from the right. When there is a mismatch, then the compiler complains. What this actually means is that you are double-declaring the variable type. In C#, if you use the `var` keyword, then the compiler automatically gives the variable the same type as the type its being assigned. If you then try to use that variable as a different type then you'll get a compiler error.